# Regexp to match multiple Strings - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

Say I have the following array of addresses

```
array = ["1 New Street, Filton Grove, Bristol BD7 0AA", "2 New Street, Filton Grove, Bristol BD7 0AA", "3 New Street, Filton Grove, Bristol BD7 0AA"]
```

I would like to check that each item in the array contains the words `Filton Grove Bristol`, but as there are commas within the address is is throwing me slightly.

How do  I ignore the commas and check that each word exists in each iteration of the array

So far I have this

```
regexp = /^Filton Grove Bristol/i
array.all? { |a| regex =~ a }
```

But this fails.

Comment: Do they ALL contain a comma?

Answer (score 2):

You could check for words separately.

```
regexp_checks = [/Filton/i, /Grove/i, /Bristol/i]
array.all? { |a| regexp_checks.all?{|rgx| a =~ rgx} }
```

Comment: This is best if you dont want the order of words :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also check in this way..

```
regexp_checks = [/Filton.*?Grove.*?Bristol/i]
array.all? { |a| regexp_checks.all?{|rgx| a =~ rgx} }
```

**Note:** Use this only if you want to maintain the order of words appearing.
And if order is important and no other words should be allowed in between.. you can use
    `regexp_checks = [/Filton\W+Grove\W+Bristol/i]`

Comment: Thank You, In my case the order of the words would be quite useful

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex

`regexp = /Filton Grove,?\s*Bristol/i`

You do not need the `^` in your regex.

Answer (score 2):

If the three words must be in the specific sequence, try this:

```
regexp = /Filton[,\s]+Grove[,\s]+Bristol/i
```

Answer (score 1):

For all possible use cases

```
regexp = /Filton[\s,\s]*Grove[\s,\s]*Bristol/i
```